# Where to look for logs in Google Connector installer for file system connector

Tags: java, connector, google-search-appliance

I am running the following command to install Google File system connector and it's failing without much info. Can you please point out to some logs or what's going on?

sudo ./GCI.bin LAX_VM /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin//java -i console

===============================================================================

### Choose Java Runtime Environment

Please choose a Java VM for use by the installed application:

->1- /usr/bin/java

```
2- Choose a Java VM already installed on this system
```

ENTER THE NUMBER FOR THE JAVA VM, OR PRESS  TO ACCEPT THE
      CURRENT SELECTION: 2
ENTER THE ABSOLUTE PATH TO THE JAVA VM EXECUTABLE OF YOUR CHOICE
      : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin//java

PATH TO THE JAVA EXECUTABLE IS:
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin//java
   (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java)
   IS THIS CORRECT? (Y/N): Y
Unable to install the Java Virtual Machine included with this installer.

and it fails.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with Java 7? I've made it worked with Java 7, but not sure if the connectors support Java 8.